# How to implement a distributed priority queue without using Zookeeper?

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed-computing, priority-queue

I want to implement a distributed priority queue without using Zookeeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to communicate between client and server (e.g. with TCP sockets) it should be straightforward. The server contains a thread safe implementation of the Priority Queue, hence providing an "interface". Clients connect to the server and uses this "interface".

### Server

The server must provide a priority queue interface (i.e. supporting `add`, `peek`, `poll`, ...). Important is that **these methods must be thread safe !** So we will use `PriorityBlockingQueue` (which is synchronized) instead of `PriorityQueue`.

```
public class Server {
    private static ServerSocket server_skt;
    public PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pq;

    // Constructor
    Server(int port, int pq_size) {
        server_skt = new ServerSocket(port);
        this.pq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer>(pq_size);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Server server = new Server(5555, 20); // Make server instance

        while(true) {
            // Always wait for new clients to connect
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
                // Spawn new thread for communication with client 
                new CommunicationThread(server_skt.accept(), server.pq).start();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured :" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how `CommunicationThread` class would look like

```
public class CommunicationThread extends Thread {
    private Socket client_socket;
    private InputStream client_in;
    private OutputStream client_out;
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pq;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket socket, PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pq) {
        try {
            this.client_socket = socket;
            this.client_in = client_socket.getInputStream();
            this.client_out = client_socket.getOutputStream(); 
            this.pq = pq;

            System.out.println("Client connected : " + client_socket.getInetAddress().toString());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize communication properly. -- CommunicationThread.\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean active = true;
        while(active) {
            int message_number = client_in.read(); // Listen for next integer --> dispatch to correct method

            switch(message_number) {
            case -1: case 0: 
                // Will stop the communication between client and server
                active = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                // Add
                int element_to_add = client_in.read(); // read element to add to the priority queue
                pq.add(element_to_add); // Note that a real implementation would send the answer back to the client
                break;
            case 2:
                // Poll (no extra argument to read)
                int res = pq.poll();

                // Write result to client
                client_out.write(res);
                client_out.flush();
                break;

            /*
             * IMPLEMENT REST OF INTERFACE (don't worry about synchronization, PriorityBlockingQueue methods are already thread safe)
             */

            }
        }

        client_in.close();
        client_out.close();
    }
}
```

This class is listening to what the client is sending.
According to what the client sent, the server knows what to do, hence there is a mini protocol. That protocol is : when the client wants to invoke a method of the distributed priority queue, he sends an integer (e.g. 2 = `poll()`). The server reads that integer and knows which method to invoke.

Note that sometimes sending one integer is enough (see `poll()` example), but not always. Think for example of `add()` which has to specify an argument. The server will receive `1` from the client (i.e. `add()`) and will read a second integer (or any other object that has to be stored in the distributed priority queue).

### Client

Based on the protocol, the server is offering the client an interface (e.g. 0 = stop communication, 1 = `add()` , ...). The client only has to connect to the server and send messages (**respecting the procotol!**) to it.

A client example :

```
public class PQ_Client {
    private static Socket skt;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    private final int _STOP_ = 0, _ADD_ = 1, _POLL_ = 2; // By convention (protocol)

    PQ_Client(String ip, int port) {
        try {
            this.skt = new Socket(ip, port);
            this.in = skt.getInputStream();
            this.out = skt.getOutputStream();

            System.out.println("Connected to distributed priority queue.");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect with the distributed priority queue : " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    // Sort of stub functions
    public void stop() {
        out.write(_STOP_);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    public void add(Integer el) {
        out.write(_ADD_); // Send wanted operation
        out.write(el);    // Send argument element

        // Real implementation would listen for result here

        out.flush();
    }

    public int poll() {
        out.write(_POLL_);
        out.flush();

        // Listen for answer
        return in.read();
    }

    /*
     * Rest of implementation
     */
}
```

Note that thanks to these self made *"stub functions"* we can make a `PQ_Client` object and use it as if it was a priority queue (the client/server communication is hidden behind the stubs).

```
String ip = "...";
int port = 5555;

PQ_Client pq = new PQ_Client(ip , port);    
pq.add(5);
pq.add(2);
pq.add(4);

int res = pq.poll();
```

Note that by using RPC (Remote Procedure Call) it could be easier (stub function generated automatically, ...).
In fact what we implemented above is a little RPC-like mechanism, as it does nothing else then sending a message to call a procedure (e.g. `add()`) on the server, serializing the result (not needed for integers), send it back to the client.

Comment: This is a *centralized* priority queue, not a *distributed* priority queue. Advantages that a distributed priority queue might provide could be scalability and high availability.